# Only calling input when function is called

Tags: python-3.x, input

How can I get input to only evaluate when my function is called, not when my app runs?

```
    def get_name(name = input('Enter a name.\n> ').rstrip()):
    '''Enter a name'''

    return name if validate_length(name, 'name') else get_name()
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by putting `name = input('Enter a name.\n> ').rstrip()` inside of the actual function instead as an argument:

```
def get_name():
    name = input('Enter a name.\n> ').rstrip()
    return name if validate_length(name, 'name') else get_name()
```